# How to fix VoiceOver swiping behavior after stopping and restarting the app, iPhone only?

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a universal app on which VoiceOver is behaving strangely, but only on the iPhone. When I delete the app and reinstall on either iPhone or iPad, VoiceOver works as expected and everything is fine. But on iPhone, if I stop the app and then restart it, VoiceOver still "works" in the sense that you can tap an element and select it for the VO focus in that way; but for some reason the left-right swiping stops working - instead of changing the focus, you just hear the "clunk" sound like you get when you reach the end of a control list.

The app is iOS-7 only. Has anybody ever encountered this problem?

Update: I've found that if I put this line in `viewDidLoad` of my app's root view controller:

```
self.view.accessibilityViewIsModal = YES;
```

everything works. Anybody understand this?

Comment: What do you mean by "stop," here? Force quit? Re-run from Xcode?

Comment: @Justin: either way of stopping and restarting (force quitting or re-running from Xcode) has this effect.